# How to plot a row against the column names in R

Tags: r, plot, row, names

I would like to plot a graph with different lines for each row, and that the  column names are assigned to the X axis. For finishing, I would also like to make every line different from the other with a legend for the reader.

Thank you in advance.

My data:

```
Average 2003-2005 Average 2006-2008 Average 2009-2010 Average 2011-2013 Average 2014-2016
         31.48489          32.53664          30.41938          30.53870          31.15550   
         18.78799           17.78141         17.58791          17.03071          17.25654   
        107.46615          107.71512        109.55090         110.31438         109.66492   

> str(Table_1_2003_2018_All)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Average 2003-2005: num  31.5 18.8 107.5
 $ Average 2006-2008: num  32.5 17.8 107.7
 $ Average 2009-2010: num  30.4 17.6 109.6
 $ Average 2011-2013: num  30.5 17 110.3
 $ Average 2014-2016: num  31.2 17.3 109.7
 $ Average 2017-2018: num  31.8 16.8 109.8
```

Code:

```
# Plot 1

colnames(Table_1_2003_2018_All) <- c("2003-2005","2006-2008","2009-2010","2011-2013","2014-2016","2017-2018")

    plot(seq_along(Table_1_2003_2018_All), 
         Table_1_2003_2018_All[1,], type="l", xaxt = 'n',xlab = 'Time Periods', ylab = 'Average',
         main = "MARKET WORK", ylim = c(30,35)
         )

    axis(1, at = 1:6, colnames(Table_1_2003_2018_All))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the 'x'  as `numeric` i.e sequence of columns and then change the x labels with `axis`

```
plot(seq_along(Table_1_2003_2018_All), 
    Table_1_2003_2018_All[1,], type="l", xaxt = 'n', 
      xlab = 'colnames', ylab = 'first row')
axis(1, at = 1:5, colnames(Table_1_2003_2018_All))
```

[image]

---

If we need to plot lines for each row, use `matplot`

```
matplot(t(Table_1_2003_2018_All), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n')
legend("top", legend = seq_len(nrow(Table_1_2003_2018_All)),
   col= seq_len(nrow(Table_1_2003_2018_All)),cex=0.8,
   fill=seq_len(nrow(Table_1_2003_2018_All)))
axis(1, at = 1:5, colnames(Table_1_2003_2018_All))
```

[image]

#### data

```
Table_1_2003_2018_All <- structure(list(Average2003.2005 = c(31.48489, 18.78799, 107.46615
), Average2006.2008 = c(32.53664, 17.78141, 107.71512), Average2009.2010 = c(30.41938, 
17.58791, 109.5509), Average2011.2013 = c(30.5387, 17.03071, 
110.31438), Average2014.2016 = c(31.1555, 17.25654, 109.66492
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: hi @akrun. Thank you. But I no plot was generated and I got the following error message:
`Error in plot.window(...) : endliche 'xlim' Werte nötig
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: Thank you. It worked, though I got this error message:
`Error in axis(1, at = 1:5, colnames(Table_1_2003_2018_All)) : 
  Length of 'at' and 'labels' different, 5! = 6`
Is there a way to fil the y-axis with values from 0 to 50, just that the display is more clear? I mean, this is 30,..., not zero to drop so strong. You know what I mean? Ty again

Comment: @Fabricio With the `dput` 'data' in my post, I am not getting any errors.  You can specify the `ylim = c(0, 50)`

Comment: I forgot that I took some columns aways for my sample here. I corrected it and it worked fantastic. Thank you. May I ask you if there's possible to set the y grid for more values than those? I mean, a sequence between 0 and 50, 100... whatever. So it is better "readable". Thank you

Comment: I've clicked twice there :)

Comment: you're welcome. I'm the one thanking you here.  I'm sorry if I may bothering you too much... but to add other lines to the other rows... and a legend for that? Is too complicated? Should I post another question to this one?

Comment: @Fabricio  Please check my updated code with the graph

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a structural error:
`> install.packages("matplot")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fabri/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘matplot’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)`
do you know how to workaround it?

Comment: @Fabricio  `matplot` is a `base R` function.  You don't need any installation

Comment: the last issue is that one row is not being printed in the graph and the legend is not displaying the rownames (I gave them names later) as well. Do you please have a supplementary code for that? ty

Comment: @Fabricio  Can you check the `str(yourdata)` as it could be an issue with rownames

Comment: I had 3 different dfs. They have the same colnames and rownames, but the values regard to 3 different things.  Now I have, for ex. colnames "2003-2005"..."2017-2018" and rownames "all", "men", "women". I would like to have one line in the plot for this rownames, to illustrate the difference among the groups.
`> str(Market_Work)
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ 2003-2005: num  31.5 37.4 31.5
 $ 2006-2008: num  32.5 38.2 32.5
 $ 2009-2010: num  30.4 35.1 30.4
 $ 2011-2013: num  30.5 35.7 30.5
 $ 2014-2016: num  31.2 36.5 31.2
 $ 2017-2018: num  31.8 36.7 31.8`

Comment: @Fabricio  Can you please post as a new question with `dput` of each of the example data.  In that way, it becomes more  clear

Comment: sure, I'm posting a new question